# Jupyter notebook keeps launching a browser

Tags: jupyter-notebook, x11, remote-access

Working on a Ubuntu server remotely shhed in with X forwarding, and running the command `jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8888`. Even though I added `--no-browser`, a laggy Firefox keeps popping up. How can I stop this?

Versions:

```
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==5.2.3
jupyter-console==6.0.0
jupyter-core==4.4.0
jupyterlab==0.35.1
jupyterlab-server==0.2.0
```

Comment: Which version of jupyter notebook are you using?

Comment: Added versions to post

Comment: "c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False" in ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py file works for me.